# Как получить значение хедера в ответе сервера на Angular Http Client?

Tags: angular2, angular

Сервер кроме данных отвечает дополнительным параметром `data_count` в заголовках headers 
Как мне, делая запрос, получить этот параметр?
Я пробую так, но это не работает

```
this.http.post<any>('Server/api/',{}
    ).subscribe((res: Response) => {
      console.log(res.headers.get('data_count'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.http.get('/api/')
  .subscribe((res: Response) => {
    console.log(res.headers);
  });
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]